# Proper way of instantiating identical entities in a single transaction?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I'm at my wits end trying to properly model my domain ([referring problem space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8OZx.png)).

It's a Meal Planner that consists of 28 days. After a user registers, they get redirected to onboarding to answer some questions (saved as MealPlanResources VO), afterwards they can select meals (from our internal recipe database) for each of the 28 days (as shown on the image above).

These are some User use cases that would supposedly interact with the Day entity.

1. A user can add/remove meals for X day.
2. A user can reset a day (remove all meals).
3. A user can mark a day as complete/incomplete (in case user
   hasn't cooked all the meals yet).

This is how I've modeled the domain so far ([folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/258Hg.png)):

**MealPlan (AR)**

```
namespace App\MealPlan\Domain\Model;

use App\MealPlan\Domain\Model\Calendar\Calendar;
use App\MealPlan\Domain\Model\Calendar\CalendarId;
use App\MealPlan\Domain\Model\Calendar\Day\Days;
use Shared\Domain\Users\UserId;

final class MealPlan {

    public function __construct(
        private MealPlanId $id, 
        private UserId $userId,
        private MealPlanResources $resources
    ){}

    public static function create(
        MealPlanId $id, 
        UserId $userId,
        MealPlanResources $resources
    ): MealPlan {
        return new self($id, $userId, $resources);
    }

    protected function createCalendar(
        CalendarId $calendarId, 
        MealPlanId mealPlanId,
        Days $days
    ): Calendar {
        return new Calendar($calendarId, $mealPlanId, $days);
    }
    
}
```

**Calendar (Entity)**

```
namespace App\MealPlan\Domain\Model\Calendar;
use App\MealPlan\Domain\Model\MealPlanId;
use App\MealPlan\Domain\Model\Calendar\Day\{Day, Days, DayState};

final class Calendar {

    public function __construct(
        private CalendarId $id,
        private MealPlanId $mealPlanId,
        private Days $days
    ){}

    public static function create(
        CalendarId $id, 
        MealPlanId $mealPlanId, 
        Days $days
    ): Calendar {
        return new self($id, $mealPlanId, $days);
    }

    public function days(): Days {
        return $this->days;
    }

    public function resetDay(Day $day): void {
        
    }

    public function getDay(int $value): Day {
        foreach($this->days->getIterator() as $day){
            if($day->getDay() === $value){
                return $day;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Day (Entity)**

```
namespace App\MealPlan\Domain\Model\Calendar\Day;

class Day {
    
    private MealCollection $meals;
    
    public function __construct(
        protected DayId $day,
        protected CalendarId $calendarId,
        protected DayState $state
    ){}

    public function changeDayState(DayState $state): void {
        // if day doesn't have 3 meals, state can't be set to DayState::COMPLETED
        // throw error

        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function addMeal(Meal $meal): void {
        // if meal already exists
        // throw error
        
        return $this->meals->add($meal);
    }
    
    public function removeMeal(): void {
        // remove meal 
    }
    
    public function getState(): DayState {
        return $this->state;
    }
}
```

Based on the above, I'd say the 28 days should be created and persisted during aggregate root creation. But I'm not sure whose responsible for adding the 28 days and persisting. Is it the MealPlan in the createCalendar method, or in the Calendar factory method itself?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the MealPlan in the createCalendar method, or in the Calendar factory method itself?

Something to note: when the first DDD book was published (Evans, 2003), domain entities were a pattern described in chapter five, but the life cycle management patterns (aggregate, factory, repository) were described in chapter *six*.

Part of the idea here is that you want to avoid mixing domain code and plumbing.  Yes, our model needs an in memory representation of calendars, and days, and so on - but the *business* doesn't particularly care about the details of how that happens in the world of the machine.

In other words, "wire everything up correctly" is a separate concern from managing how information changes in our model of the domain.

So it might follow from the "single responsibility principle" that we want the "wire everything up" code to be isolated in a single module with that responsibility.

All else being equal, this might suggest that our first guess should be to put as much of the "wire everything up" code into the factory methods, and let the domain entities concentrate on the domain.

It may help to think about what you want your code to look like when you are loading an aggregate from your durable information store.  Creating a MealPlan looks a lot like loading a MealPlan from a database - the main difference being that you are getting the information from "somewhere else".